# Getting array declaration error

Tags: c

I have this array called `arr_[6]`, having an idea of including six strings...but when I declare this array compiler throws error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    char arr_1[]= {"My_name","your Name", "His Name"};


    char *arr_p;

    arr_p = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);

    arr_p = arr_1;

    printf("%s\n",*arr_p);


    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Shown errors are as follows:

```
> main.c: In function `main': main.c:9: error: excess elements in char
> array initializer main.c:9: error: (near initialization for `arr_1')
> main.c:9: error: excess elements in char array initializer main.c:9:
> error: (near initialization for `arr_1')
> 
> make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    const char *arr_1[]= {"My_name","your Name", "His Name"}; // has to be an array of <char *>

    //arr_p is not necessary

    printf("%s\n",*arr_1); // will print the first string, "My_name"
    printf("%s\n",arr_1[1]); // will print the second string, "your Name"
    printf("%s\n",arr_1[2]); // will print the third string, "His Name"
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int i;
    char* arr_1[]= {"My_name","your Name", "His Name", NULL};
    char** arr_p;

    arr_p = arr_1;

    i = 0;
    while (arr_p[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",(arr_p[i]));
        ++i;
    }

   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

These are the list of changes I've made:

1. Use `char* arr_1[]` to declare an array of strings, since each string is an array of characters.
2. If you need a pointer to a char*, you need to declare the pointer to be of datatype `char**`
3. Used NULL as the last element in the array, so that you know when you've reached the end of the array of strings.
4. Use a `while` loop to iterate over all the strings.

Comment: Thanks my friend...i was actually trying for this only....I appreciate your efforts...thanks!